# How to restrict the RIGHT table in a LEFT join to a single row (with preference of a particular row)?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

The problem is that I can't seem to refer to anything outside of the subquery!?

```
SELECT * FROM currentcalls AS c
LEFT JOIN custprices ON c.rateid = custprices.rateid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM costprices 
    WHERE costprices.ratetype = custprices.ratetype
      AND (costprices.providerid = c.providerid OR costprices.providerid=0)
    ORDER BY costprices.providerid DESC LIMIT 1) AS new1 ON new1.ratetype = custprices.ratetype
```

3 Tables:

```
currentcalls (rateid, providerid)
custprices (rateid, ratetype)
costprices (ratetype,providerid)
```

We want ALL rows from currentcalls, and a single row from cust and cost prices.
rateid has a unique row, so custprices is fine.

Unfortunately though, the costprice for a particular providerid may not exist (in which case I want to use providerid=0), or if it DOES exist, then I don't want the providerid=0 results. Either way, I do not want multiple rows (from costprice) returned.

**SAMPLE DATA** (pricing_information represents multiple fields that I want to select)

```
currentcalls (rateid, providerid)
              345       2
custprices (rateid, ratetype)
              345     123
costprices (ratetype,providerid, pricing_information)
              123       0           ????A
              123       1           ????B
              123       2           ????C
              123       3           ????D
```

I want the result to be:

```
rateid,providerid,rateid,ratetype,ratetype,providerid,pricing_information
  345      2       345     123     123       2           ??????C
```

And if the providerid doesn't exist, then the result should be

```
  345      2       345     123     123       0           ??????A
```

(For each row in the current calls table there should only be 1 instance of custprices which is easy because the ID is unique, but the trouble is getting only ONE instance of pricing_information, relevent to the providerid and ratetype)

Comment: Can you make sqlfiddle with sample data and expected result.

Comment: Updated again for the "When providerid doesn't exist" results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  c.rateid, 
        c.providerid, 
        new1.ratetype, 
        new1.pricing_information
FROM    currentcalls AS c
        LEFT JOIN custprices d
            ON c.rateid = d.rateid
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  a.*
            FROM    costprices a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  ratetype, MAX(x.providerid) min_provid
                        FROM    costprices x
                                INNER JOIN currentcalls y
                                  ON x.providerid IN (y.providerid, 0)
                    ) b ON  a.ratetype = b.ratetype AND
                            a.providerid = b.min_provid
        ) AS new1 ON new1.ratetype = d.ratetype;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e35/9)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*not existing*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e88a2/1)

Comment: When I tried that, it did only return one row, however it returned the row with providerid=0 instead of the row with providerid=1 (The data in currentcalls table as providerid=1)

Comment: sorry for that. change `MIN(providerid)` into `MAX(providerid)`

Comment: Just to explain further: I only want it to return the lowest providerid (i.e 0) if it can't match currentcalls.providerid to costprices.providerid (But at the same time, it must always match currentcalls.ratetype to costprices.ratetype)

Comment: I actually tried MAX(providerid) as well, and it chose the highest providerid for that ratetype in costprices (which is higher that the currentcalls.providerid value)

Comment: It seems to me that where you have "a.providerid = b.min_provid" - shouldn't that reference the currentcalls.providerid somehow?

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result? it is much easy to understand `:D`

Comment: Ok I will edit the main post since someone else also asked - thanks for your time :)

Comment: Wow. SQLFiddle is amazing! Your code definitely works in that. I'll give it a try on my DB.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get the code to work on my production DB. I simply get NULL results instead of any matches for costprices.

Comment: @Alex then something might be missing. Are those records posted above the as with your records on production db?

Comment: Your answer does work in SQLFiddle with my sample data, so I have marked your answer as 'Accepted'. I was hoping for a simpler solution, but it seems like there will need to be a lot of subqueries/sub-joins and stuff that might cause strain on the DB when it's all loaded up. With that in mind, I've decided to do a second query in PHP to get the cost data required. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm willing to help `:D` what else do you need?